# is it possible to ssh into docker container which is not running ( or exited )?

Tags: docker

By using **exec** command we can ssh in to docker instance which is running.
Is there any way to ssh in to docker instance which is not running?

Comment: You're asking how to connect to a turned-off computer. That's impossible. Or maybe you want to put commands in a queue which will be executed once the instance will run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A Docker instance that is not running is not running. You could start it for ssh directly, though.